# PHP Group keys of associative array by values

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

```
function groupByOwners(array $files) : array { return []; }

$files = array("Input.txt" => "Randy","Code.py" => "Stan","Output.txt" =>"Randy"); 

Print_r(groupByOwners($files);
```

My expected output is:

```
[Randy => [Input.txt, Output.txt] , Stan => [Code.py]]
```

Answer (score 2):

You just need to iterate over your array, pushing each filename to a new array indexed by the names:

```
function groupByOwners(array $files) : array { 
    $output = array();
    foreach ($files as $file => $name) {
        $output[$name][] = $file;
    }
    return $output;
}

$files = array("Input.txt" => "Randy","Code.py" => "Stan","Output.txt" =>"Randy"); 

print_r(groupByOwners($files));
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [Randy] => Array
        (
            [0] => Input.txt
            [1] => Output.txt
        )
    [Stan] => Array
        (
            [0] => Code.py
        )
)
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/b6MBU)